# Simple PHP class, undefined variable?

Tags: php

I'm learning about classes and objects in PHP, and I'm getting really confused. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

class ipInfo {
    public $test1 = 'test';
}

$test = new ipInfo();
echo $test->$test1;

?>
```

Whenever I run it, I get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: test1 in //// on line 9

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in //// on line 9
```

Comment: Lose the `$`  in `->$test1`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the right syntax can be found in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Object properties don't need the second `$` (unless you are using variable varibles).

```
echo $test->test1;
```

You use the `$` to reference the variable and then the `->` to specify which propery you are looking at.

If you on the other hand have a variable with the value of `test1` called `$var` you could do this:

```
$var='test1';
echo $test->$var;
```

Which would work as the code would interpret the VALUE inside the $var and assume you meant that property.

Answer (score 2):

You dont access them with a `$` sign:

try:

```
echo $test->test1;
```